# get all inherited as well as current vars of object in php

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a class hierarchy as below:

```
class A extends B{}
abstract class B extends C{ private $a;private $b;private $c;}
abstract class C { function func1(){}}
```

in this i am supposed to call like this:

```
$a=new A();
$a->func1();
```

now func1() needs to get the current class variables and all of them, inherited as well as the ones in the current class.

how can i access them. i tried the

> get_object_vars

and also

> get_class_vars

but they only returned me current class vars that is none as per class hierarchy given above.

what should i do. please help

Comment: Are the properties declared like is the case here? Because that's invalid syntax. If not: are they `private`, `protected` or `public`? you have another syntax error here: `abstract class C { function func1(){};}` <-- the last semi-colon shouldn't be there

Comment: i have updated the code. can u please comment now..??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Yes I can: cange `private` to `protected`! The difference being `protected` properties are visible throughout the entire inheritance chain, `private` properties are only visible within the class that defines them

Comment: Thanks it work..if you wish please post it as an answer...site is not allowing me to accept my own answer for 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the comment of  Elias Van Ootegem.

I had kept all the variables as private and then forgot that wont be visible to the outside world.

Now it is fixed. Thanks :)